# Does convergence imply uniform convergence in this example?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, sequence-of-function

Consider a map
\begin{align}
F:&[0~1]^\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}\\
&\{x_k\}\rightarrow \{y_k\}=F\{x_k\}
\end{align}
with the following properties:

1. $\{y_k\} \rightarrow 0$ for all $\{x_k\}\in[0~1]^\mathbb{N}$
2. $y_k=f(y_{k-1},x_k)$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, where $f(\cdot,\cdot)$ is a continuous function and $y_0$ is a given constant.

Can we guarantee all the possible sequences $\{y_k\}$ converge uniformly to zero?

Comment: How are you defining uniform convergence of all sequences $\{y_k\}$ to zero? Is the idea that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there is some $N$, independent of the choice of $\{y_k\} = F\{x_k\}$, such that $\lvert y_k\rvert < \epsilon$ for all $k\geq N$?

Comment: Yes, that's it.